# Denominator in pairwise similarities in symmetric SNE

Tags: notation, tsne

I am trying to understand how symmetric SNE (stochastic neighbour embedding) works while reading [the paper of Van der Maaten about t-SNE](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/vandermaaten08a/vandermaaten08a.pdf).

However, I am a bit confused about the denominator in the following expression for the pairwise similarity:

$$ q_{ij} = \frac{\exp(-\|y_i-y_j\|^2)}{\sum_{k\ne l}\exp(-\|y_j-y_k\|^2)}.$$

What exactly is it that we are summing over? What is $k$ and what is $l$? 
Is it the difference between any pair of $y$-vectors among all $n$ datapoints in the low-dimensional space?

Comment: Yes, this is the sum over all possible $n(n-1)$ pairs.